# Detecting sprite object within a sprite group on collision

Tags: python, pygame

I am new to pygame and I am working on a distributed peer-peer multiplayer game. I tried doing the following but I was not able to figure out how.

I have a player class and an enemy class. The player and enemies are all part of different sprite groups. Say in a 4 player game where there is one player object and 3 enemy objects, When a player fires , I use the spritecollide method to check collision with the enemy sprite group. But I want to identify in specific as to which enemy has been shot within the spritegroup. I am quite not able to figure that out. Is that even possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as it sounds like enemy objects and player objects can do the same thing, maybe you should have one common class for both `enemy` and `player`.

This could be called for example a `creature` class. Then based on if the `creature` is a `enemy` or `player` you can control it using an `EnemyAI` class or a `UserInput` class.

As for identifying who was hit, you can easily add a `name` variable within each of the `creature` classes that you define upon declaring a new `creature`. Then when you evaluate hits, you can have the function return the `name` of the `creature` who was hit.

Comment: The reason I had different classes for each of them was because , the player would be controlled locally , while the location of the enemy objects and their actions would be updated through the network by other players part of the game as and when they perform an action. I didnt quite understand the last part. So for example say i have an enemyAI class which extends pygame.sprite.Sprite. WIthin this class , I have to over ride the update func and within this update function , I would check for collision with the enemy sprite group. How will I identify the name of the object within the group ?

Comment: @user3416372, I wouldnt extend the creature as EnemyAI, I would just give it a reference to the creature you want to control, and a list of the other creatures it must fight. This way every player or enemy can evaluate in their own viewpoint. Then have this list of creatures in a main update which will control things like movement and drawing